# How to select transformer

Tags: transformer, flyback

I want to design a flyback switch mode power supply.

I used WBench from TI.

I inputted my specifications and I got this for the transformer.

[image]

How do I use this information to choose an off-the-shelf transformer from Digikey?

Comment: There are some multitap transformers which aim to cover cases like yours but for mass production, you’re better off with a custom design.

Comment: @winny how do I even do a custom design? Who will do it for me? What are my options?

Comment: There are many companies who only do customer specific transformers. Developing it and making drawings for them is almost a lost art form when new engineers only want to learn AI and crate mobile games. You can make an entire career out of just SMPS transformer design.

Comment: @winny comment of the year! hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the parts listed in your image but, realistically, you would need to search for transformers that: -

- Didn't saturate too much on the peak primary current
- Were suitable for the switching frequency i.e. losses were not too great
- Had a secondary winding that is roughly suitable for the target output DC voltage and peak current

However, as with most flyback transformers, it is quite normal to custom wind. Alternatively, you might be able to use a suitable one from [Premier Magnetics](https://premiermag.com/power-magnetics/). They have off-the-shelf solutions to a lot of applications especially those that use [Power Integrations devices](https://www.power.com/?segment=none). Here is an [example of a few UL/CSA recognized designs](https://premiermag.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/UL-CSA-Recognized-Top-Switch-Transformers.pdf) of which some may be suitable: -

[image]

I'm steering you this way because I know that the choices from the regular distributors can be somewhat limited (whereas Premier Magnetics do stock parts and provide full schematics): -

[image]